# How do I format the initial value with JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I want to change the default decimal format for a JSpinner, specifying a number of decimal places but leaving other formatting locale specific.

But if I do this

```
@Test public void fails() {
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner);
    editor.getFormat().setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
    spinner.setEditor(editor);
    assertEquals(0, spinner.getValue());
    assertEquals("0.000", ((NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().getText());
        // FAIL HERE with "0"

    spinner.setValue(0.01);
    assertEquals("0.010", ((NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().getText());
}
```

as I think I found in Sun example code, the initial formatted value is "0", as the changes to the format have not been detected.

I can set the format picture explicitly

```
@Test public void delMe() {
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner, "0.000"));
    assertEquals(0, spinner.getValue());
    assertEquals("0.000", ((NumberEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().getText());
}
```

but this does not respect locale settings with regards to commas etc.

Comment: What, not even a vote for the question, and only 11 views?

Comment: Duncan, this was missing the Java tag, so it most likely did not get nearly the same amount of attention as it should have. I will add the java tag now.

Comment: Thank you [grrr comment length constraints]